# How do I pass my Form Data which is in the child component to the parent component(which also contains a form) and on submit log all the data?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So I have a parent component which contains a form and a child component(this component also has a form , here its a dynamic form meaning when the add button is hit it creates another form below so that user can add a list of parameters of various types . Basically I am trying to achieve state lifting from child to component . I would be really grateful if someone could help me out , I have been stuck on this since a week and I tried a lot . I would appreciate if someone could refactor my code so that it works . I have also attached a gif which shows the form

GIF : https://drive.google.com/file/d/15YXGhvo0OMCh4ch44q4S88wcqOB7i2ew/view?usp=sharing

**Parent Component - ParamsForm.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
import styles from '../style.module.css'
import Operations from './Operations'
import OperationsFormTest from './OperationsFormTest'


const ParamsForm = () => {
    const[isToggled,setIsToggled] = useState(false)

    const[formData,setFormData] = useState(
      {url:'',endpoint:'',name:'',description:'',type:'',required:''}
    )


    const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log('Form Data is :' , formData)
    }

    const handleChangeInput = (index,e) =>{
      const values = [...formData]
      values[index][e.target.name] = e.target.value
      setFormData(values)
    }

    const handleAddFields = () =>{
      setFormData([...formData,{url:'',endpoint:'',name:'',description:'',type:'',required:''}])
    }
  
    const handleRemoveFields = (index) =>{
      const values = [...formData]
      values.splice(index,1)
      setFormData(values)
    }

    

    useEffect(()=>{
      console.log(isToggled)
    },[isToggled])

  return (
    <div className={styles.paramFormsContainer}>
      {setFormData}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type='text' name='url' placeholder='Url..' value={formData.url} onChange={handleChangeInput}></input>
        <input type='text' name='endpoint' placeholder='Endpoint...' value={formData.endpoint} style={{flex : 1 }} onChange={handleChangeInput}></input>
        <button type='button' onClick={()=>setIsToggled(!isToggled)} className={styles.pathParamFormsBtn}>Path Params</button>
        
        {isToggled && <OperationsFormTest name={formData.name} description={formData.description} type={formData.type} required={formData.required} handleAddFields={handleAddFields} nameFunc={handleChangeInput} descriptionFunc={handleChangeInput} typeFunc={handleChangeInput} requiredFunc={handleChangeInput}  handleRemoveFields={handleRemoveFields}></OperationsFormTest>}
        <br></br><br></br>
        <button type='submit' onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </form>
      
    </div>
  )
}
export default ParamsForm
```

**Child Component - OperationsFormTest.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import styles from '../style.module.css'
import {FaInfo,FaFileInvoiceDollar} from 'react-icons/fa'
import ReactTooltip from "react-tooltip";

const OperationsFormTest = ({name,type,description,required,nameFunc,descriptionFunc,typeFunc,requiredFunc,handleAddFields,handleRemoveFields}) =>{

    const ChildToParentName = (e) =>{
        nameFunc(e)
    }

    const ChildToParentType = (e) =>{
        typeFunc(e)
    }

    const ChildToParentDescription = (e) =>{
        descriptionFunc(e)
    }

    const ChildToParentRequired = (e) =>{
        requiredFunc(e)
    }
    

    

    return(
        <>
            <div>
                    <div className={styles.pathParamsFormParentContainer}>
                        <div  className={styles.pathParamsFormChildContainer}>
                            <label>Name : </label>
                            <input name='name' type='text' placeholder='Name..' value={name} onChange={ChildToParentName}></input><br></br><br></br>
                            <label>Description : </label>
                            <input name='description' type='text' placeholder='Description..' value={description} onChange={ChildToParentDescription}></input><br></br><br></br>
                            <select name = 'type' value = {type} onChange={ChildToParentType}>
                                <option>Any</option>
                                <option>String</option>
                                <option>Boolean</option>
                            </select>
                            <label>Required : </label>
                            <input name='required' type='text' placeholder='Yes or No..' value={required} onChange={ChildToParentRequired}></input><br></br><br></br>
                            <button type='button' onClick={()=>handleAddFields()}>Add</button>
                            <button type='button' onClick={()=>handleRemoveFields()}>Remove</button><br></br><br></br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default OperationsFormTest
```

Comment: codesandbox link?

Comment: Let me know if you are able to access it

Comment: gives errors while typing into url text box `formData is not iterable`

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will get some idea from this simple codes.

```
function Home() {
  // Async await is up to you
  const onSubmit = async (data)=> {
    console.log(data);
  }

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} />
  )
}

function Form() {
  const [text,setText] = useState("");

  // async await is up to you
  const handleSubmit = async (e)=> {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    await onSubmit(text);

    setText("");
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type={"text"} value={text} onChange={e=>setText(e.target.value)} />
      <input type={"submit"} />
    </form>
  )
}
```